# Fibonacci! Recursive printf

Tags: c, recursion, variable-assignment, fibonacci

I have been asked to do this:

```
Please input Number: 4
+-+-+-+
+
+
+-+
+
Total is 5
```

Other Examples"

```
Please input Number: 5
+-+-+-+-+
+
+
+-+
+
+
+-+-+
+
+
total is  8
```

While this problem is driving me insane. I have been coding and researching how fibonacci works while figuring out the pattern.

The best code that I ever come up is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int fibo(int condition)
{
    if(condition <= 2)
    {
        return printf("+");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("+");
        printf("-");
        printf("\n");
        fibo(condition - 2) + fibo(condition - 1);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int takeNumber;

    printf("Please give a number!\n");
    scanf("%d",&takeNumber);
    fibo(takeNumber);
    getch();
}
```

He was very strict on the "only recursion rule"

I am confused and frustrated, I dont know if I should have seperated the " + ", " - " and the "prinf("\n"); ". I have tried it and got the stack overflow error.

It has been hard to study the pattern, can somebody help me out?

Comment: This code wouldn't even compile! What is the real code that you have written?

Comment: For one, don't return `printf("+")`, but do the `printf` and return the fibonacci number. Second, make sure you enclose the `printf`'s inside the else by braces (`{` and `}`). Also, you are not returning the result of `fibo(c-2)+fibo(c-1)` which you should.

Comment: That is my code, it works on my computer.

Comment: Finally, could you explain what exactly is the output? I mean lines with 4, 1, 1, 2 and 1 pluses doesn't seem like fubonacci to me!

Comment: My " return printf("+");
Was for : +-+-+- and the return printf("+");
Which Makes: +-+-+-+

Comment: Are there other examples apart from 4? Do you know what the pattern above is supposed to mean? A link to the assignment would help if one exists.

Comment: Always use braces {} after if or else, even if you only intend to use one expression below it. Otherwise you will easily get bugs like you did in this program. You also have an error case where the function does not return anything.

Comment: I don't have a problem with printing the last `+`. I don't see why you are returning the return value of `printf`. If you are not interested in the fibonacci value that you are computing, make your function `void` and simply write a `return` **after** `printf("+");`

Comment: Why on earth are you printing `"+"`, `"-"`, and `"\n"` in different, adjacent `printf`s?

Comment: @Kevin, I have to follow the pattern that I couldn't understand.

Comment: And it should at least print a warning because `fibo` is declared as returning an `int` but doesn't `return` anything if you hit the `else`.

Comment: `printf("+-\n");` prints all at once.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks. I did try it and it appeared differently.

Comment: It still didn't work. It was different to the pattern.

Comment: By the way, in your second example, did you mean to write only one line of `+` between the lines of `+-+` and `+-+-+`?

Comment: Guys, have you noticed the output looks like a fractal "F"?

Comment: @JuanDelCarlos, do you have a rule for generating that output? If so, can you give it? If not, how are you making the examples? Can you give a bigger example? For example for N=6 and N=7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int fibo(int condition)
{
    if(condition < 2)
    {
        printf("+\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int n0,n1;
        printf("+-");
        n1 = fibo(condition - 1);
        n0 = fibo(condition - 2);
        return  n0 + n1;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int takeNumber;

    printf("Please input Number: ");
    scanf("%d",&takeNumber);
    printf("Total is %d\n", fibo(takeNumber));
    getch();
}
```

Comment: I fixed your code, by your commet and output sample. I want to ask the meaning of the program, too.

Comment: I don't even know, he just gave us the document. With no clues or what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do, is this:

```
int fibo (int n)
{
    printf("%d ", n);  // replace this with fancy + printing...

    if(n <= 2)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        return fibo(n- 2) + fibo(n- 1);
    }
}
```

A recursive function is just like any other function: if it returns something it must do so for all cases. You only returned a value during some conditions and therefore you invoked undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin, although your answer is correct for computing fibonacci numbers, I am suspecting that the homework requires the fancy + printing itself to be done recursively. If you notice, each plus is like a 1 that add up to the number, so probably the designer of the problem meant them to be printed separately, adding up eventually to the fibonacci number